# Symbols in ARM Scatter file

Tags: linker, arm, keil, realview

Just like we can use Load, Execution regions symbols using ARM Scatter file in c source code.
Is it possible to define your own symbol in Scatter file and use it in c source?

Answer (score 0):

you can define your symbols in a headerfile then include it in the scatterfile using the command at the beginning of the scatter file

`#! armcc -E`

http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0474i/Chdiehag.html